# ListDeleteValue - Remove Part of List

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Trying to remove a userid from a given list.  Can't seem to crack it... Errors on the removal at the ListDeleteValue - something I'm missing. On CF8.

```
 <cfset curlist = "#userssigned#"> - say userx:usery:userz
 <cfset ud = "#session.user_id#"> - say userz

 <cfoutput>
 #curlist#
 <br>
 <br>
 #ud#
 <br>

 <cfset newlist = ListDeleteValue( curlist, "#ud#", ":") />

 #newlist# - should delete userz? end up as userx:usery
 </cfoutput>
```

Comment: There is no such function as [ListDeleteValue](http://cfdocs.org/listdeletevalue)

Comment: Sorry was from some Nadel notes - but it was declared as function - my bad... Only saw the listdeletevalue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `ListDeleteAt()` and also need to find the position of the item in the list using `ListFind()`
This code works below

Note: You don't need to use `"##"` when you're setting a variable to another variable

```
<cfset userssigned = 'userx:usery:userz' />
<cfset session.user_id = 'userz' />

<cfset curlist = userssigned />
<cfset ud = session.user_id />

<cfoutput>
 #curlist#<br><br>
 #ud#<br>
 <cfset newlist = ListDeleteAt( curlist, ListFind(userssigned,ud,":"), ":") />
 #newlist# - should delete userz? end up as userx:usery
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: See caveat in @JamesPrivett's answer

Answer (score 3):

I Just came across this and I think the solution provided may error if listFind() does not produce a results. You may consider the following

```
<cfset listPos = ListFind(userssigned,ud,":")>
<cfif listPos>
    <cfset newlist = ListDeleteAt( curlist, listPos , ":") />
</cfif>
```